# Converting output of AES encryption to a format preserving one (FPE)

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have an existing Java code in which I am encrypting the data received using an AES-256 encryption but I am getting the output as a longer text I want the data to preserve the format for example if I enter a phone number(10 digits) the output should be some phone number(10 digits) similarly for other sensitive fields like credit card number(16 digits) the output should be 16 random digits.

What I found is that we have 3 algorithms proposed for this work FFX , BPS and VFPE.

I have just written the basic encryption code similar to this https://howtodoinjava.com/security/java-aes-encryption-example/
and was trying to understand it but I am not able to its totally out of my understanding anyone who has a simpler understanding of the algorithm please help.

I just expect some resource or some basic understanding of BPS or anyone who would have implemented (as the documentation https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/block-cipher-techniques/documents/bcm/proposed-modes/bps/bps-spec.pdf  is confusing ). Please help as to how to do it and I am a newbie at it so even the slightest clue will be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: The length of the output of any block cipher is always the block size (16 bytes for AES). Encrypting more data is usually done with a block cipher mode of operation which chains multiple block encryptions together and consequently produces a multiple of the block size. You have to pick a stream cipher to get equal length output. Some modes such as CFB or OFB construct stream ciphers from block ciphers.

Comment: There are some libraries (few?) that provide FPE. When I need to consider it in a design (not often), I go back to Bellare and Rogaway's paper at [Format-Preserving Encryption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/251.pdf). Note: a well designed system usually will not need FPE. A well desgined system is not sensitive to lengths or alphabets. A well designed system has the crypto built-in, not tacked-on.

Comment: @Peter thanks that was valuable information.

Comment: @jww thanks, I got your point will see the paper.

Answer (score 1):

As of late 2021, you probably want to use NIST approved FPE and not the older FFX or BPS. There are two Open Source libraries which support this, [Mysto](https://github.com/mysto/java-fpe) and [Bouncy Castle](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java).